# Checking if a row already exists in SQL Server database using stored procedure

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have inserted two rows with the same content of a table still the code for searching existing data is not returning the desired result.

This is my VB.Net code:

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click

    Try

If DateTimePicker1.Value.Date >= DateTime.Parse(TxtDateFrom.Text) And DateTimePicker1.Value.Date <= DateTime.Parse(TxtDateTo.Text) Then


    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
            cmd1 = New SqlCommand("check_sched", connection)
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim rd As SqlDataReader
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", Label17.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datesched", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timefrom", TimePicker1.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeto", TimePicker1.Text)
            rd = cmd1.ExecuteReader()


            If rd.HasRows Then

                MsgBox("Employee already assigned a job for the particular time period", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Change Time Period")

            Else

                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                cmd = New SqlCommand("insert_schedule1", connection)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@actid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Label2.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@activity", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CmbActivity.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@serviceid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Label14.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@servicename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtServiceType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdatefrom", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtDateFrom.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdateto", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtDateTo.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@deptname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Label16.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CmbEmp.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Label17.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@datesched", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDate1
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@timefrom", SqlDbType.Time).Value = TimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@timeto", SqlDbType.Time).Value = TimePicker2.Value.TimeOfDay
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "1"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Scheduled Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Task Schedule")
                CmbActivity.Text = ""
                TxtServiceType.Text = ""
                TxtDateFrom.Text = ""
                TxtDateTo.Text = ""
                'CmbSactivity.Text = ""
                CmbEmp.Text = ""
                DateTimePicker1.Text = Now
                TimePicker1.Text = TimeOfDay
                TimePicker2.Text = TimeOfDay
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Please select a date within the duration", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Invalid Date")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me find the error?

This is my stored procedure

```
create procedure check_sched
    @empid int,
    @datesched datetime,
    @timefrom datetime,
    @timeto datetime
as 
begin
    SELECT * 
    FROM tbl_schedule 
    WHERE empid = @empid 
      AND datesched = @datesched 
      AND timefrom >= @timefrom 
      AND timeto <= @timeto
end
```

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_schedule]
(   
     [actid] [int] NULL,    
     [activity] [nvarchar](350) NULL,   
     [serviceid] [int] NULL,    
     [servicename] [nvarchar](50) NULL,     
     [pdatefrom] [nvarchar](50) NULL,   
     [pdateto] [nvarchar](50) NULL,     
     [sactid] [int] NULL,   
     [sactivity] [nvarchar](500) NULL,  
     [deptname] [nvarchar](150) NULL,   
     [emp] [nvarchar](150) NULL,    
     [empid] [int] NULL,    
     [datesched] [datetime] NULL,   
     [timefrom] [datetime] NULL,    
     [timeto] [datetime] NULL,
     [actimefrom] [datetime] NULL,  
     [actimeto] [datetime] NULL,
     [completed] [int] NULL,    
     [status] [int] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Please provide the table structure and desired results.

Comment: Edited the question with table definiton.The problem now am facing is this code doesnt show any error, But if i entered two fields with the same empid , datesched,timefrom and timeto it should display the message box that employee already assigned for another job at that time period.

Comment: And instead the data is again added into the database showing message box "Scheduled Successfully"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your check schedule uses the `TimePicker1` value for both `@timeFrom` and `@timeTo` fields, while your insert uses `TimePicker1` and `TimePicker2` respectively. This is causing your check to look at the wrong dates.

To avoid this issue in the future and to make it easier to find these bugs, try refactoring the names to match what they are for (such as `fromTimePicker` and `toTimePicker`).

Comment: Also, I would suggest checking if the employee is already assigned for another job at that time period inside the INSERT stored procedure and have it return a bit output parameter indicating success or fail.